# I'm new to coding but when I exit Visual Studio Code it must auto-save

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm new to coding but when I exit Visual Studio Code it must auto-save.

I have made changes to my code which is now causing problems, I think it's because it has updated the file `widget_test.dart` - is it possible to UNDO these changes and go back to a working version at all, Edit > Undo won't undo it probably because I exited Visual Studio Code before I realised there was a problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't undo it because you quit Visual Studio Code. Visual Studio Code only allows you to undo code changes you made this time you opened it. I suggest you take a look at [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmcoSw3freA) on how to pop up a dialog asking you to confirm before exiting.

Press  <kbd>Command</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>P</kbd>  and enter Open Settings and open the `settings.json` file. The setting is called `window.confirmBeforeClose` and can have 2 notable options:

- `keyboardOnly`
- `always`

You should `always` type because the `always` option will bring up a confirmation dialog whenever you try to quit the application, whether through a keybinding or with the mouse.

Comment: Thank you @My Car for your reply. I have changed that setting now, Interesting that it isn't just a tick box in preferences and has to be added as code. Also, this just confirms you want to exit, rather than asking if you want to save your project or not.

Comment: @rnmuk yes it's just to confirm if you want to quit so you don't accidentally quit Visual Studio Code without being able to undo the code

Comment: @rnmuk although the project is saved, you can undo the code